# trying to print and get: "cannot be resolved to a variable" error

Tags: java

I cannot understand why in the following code:

```
System.out.println("Enter start time");
String startTime = console.nextLine();
String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");
double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
double pickupMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);{
 if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 ){
 int peaktimeWage = 4;}
 else if  (starttimeHours >=1 && starttimeHours <=5 ){
  int peaktimeWage = 2;}

else {int peaktimeFare = 3;}{
  System.out.println(peaktimeWage);
```

I keep getting the error " peaktimeWage cannot be resolved to a variable". At the last line of code which is:

```
  System.out.println(peaktimeWage);
```

Because it is a variable defined previously, and even says next to the variable up there that the variable is not used. I checked that I have written it in the same as previous code when printing out. So I do not know what the problem is. Anyone know?

Comment: Life is much simpler when you actually surrounding things with curly braces. `{ }`

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `peaktimeWage` is limited to your `if` and `else`. Decalre it outside your `if else`

```
int peaktimeWage = -1;
if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 ){
    peaktimeWage = 4;
} else if  (starttimeHours >=1 && starttimeHours <=5 ){
    peaktimeWage = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you didn't define `peaktimeWage` anywhere the compiler can see for sure.  At compile time, the compiler doesn't know that either of those if statements are going to evaluate for sure.

```
System.out.println("Enter start time");
String startTime = console.nextLine();
String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");
double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
double pickupMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
int peaktimeWage = 0; // Have a default value in case it doesn't get set
if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 )
{
     peaktimeWage = 4;
}
else if (starttimeHours >=1 && starttimeHours <=5 )
{
     peaktimeWage = 2;
}
else
{
     int peaktimeFare = 3;
}
System.out.println(peaktimeWage);
```

You're also going to have a problem with `peaktimeFare`, considering it's only defined if those other if statements are false.  (Unless `peaktimeFare` = `peaktimeWage`)

Comment: ok Wires77, thanks. I thought it picked it up in the if else block, as it did not complain when I wrote it there

Answer (score 0):

It is not defined in the environment, it's defined inside the `if` clause (so the scope of this variable is only inside the `if` or inside the `else if`), so once you've done executing the `if` - it doesn't exist...

By the way - you're missing two closing brackets `}`

Change your code to:

```
int peaktimeWage = 0;
System.out.println("Enter start time");
String startTime = console.nextLine();
String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");
double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
double pickupMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
{
 if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 ){
 peaktimeWage = 4;}
 else if  (starttimeHours >=1 && starttimeHours <=5 ){
  peaktimeWage = 2;}

 else {int peaktimeFare = 3;}
{
  System.out.println(peaktimeWage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

variable scope is incorrect.

change your

```
if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 ){
     int peaktimeWage = 4;
} else if  (starttimeHours >=1 && starttimeHours <=5 ){
      int peaktimeWage = 2;
}
```

to

```
int peaktimeWage = -1;
int peaktimeWage = -1;

if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 ){
  peaktimeWage = 4;
} else if  (starttimeHours >=1 && starttimeHours <=5 ){
  peaktimeWage = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the scope of the variable in question. This is what you've written:

```
if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 ){
 int peaktimeWage = 4;
}
```

The above statement means that the scope of the variable `peaktimeWage` is within the `if` statement only. Any statement outside would not see the existence of the variable.

**Solution:** Define the variable outside the `if` block and possibly modify the value within this block.

Answer (score 0):

peaktimeWage is being declared inside an if block.
This means it will go out of scope at the end of that if block and be cleaned up by the garbage collector.  You will also have the same issue with the peaktimeFare variable

Instead try

```
System.out.println("Enter start time");
String startTime = console.nextLine();
String [] tokens = startTime.split(":");
double starttimeHours = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]);
double pickupMinutes = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
{    
int peaktimeWage = 0;
int peaktimeFare = 0;
 if (starttimeHours >=6 && starttimeHours <=9 ){
 peaktimeWage = 4;}
 else if  (starttimeHours >=1 && starttimeHours <=5 ){
  peaktimeWage = 2;}

else {peaktimeFare = 3;}{
  System.out.println(peaktimeWage);
```